# Верстка: вложенный списки, наследование :first-child

Tags: html, css

Выпадающее меню верстается при помощи сложенных списков.

```
<div id="sidebar">
            <ul class="dropdown">
                <li><a href="">Продукция</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Мебель из стекла</a>

                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="">Столы обеденные</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Столы журнальные</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Столы по индивидуальным проектам</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">ТВ тумбы</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">ТВ стойки</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Стеклянные компьютерные и офисные столы</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Цельно-стеклянная мебель</a></li>
                        </ul>

                </li>
                <li><a href="">Стекло триплекс</a></li>
            </ul>
</div>
```

при этом для первого пункта списка class="dropdown" заданы свои свойства через

```
#sidebar ul.dropdown li:first-child {
    background: url('../images/menu_header_item.png') no-repeat;
    width: 272px;
    height: 44px;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: 'Book Antiqua', serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 12px;
    padding-left: 0;
    list-style-image: none;
    margin-bottom: -10px;
    }

#sidebar ul.dropdown li:first-child  a {
    color: #ffffff;
    }
```

в результате первый пункт вложенного списка

```
#sidebar ul.dropdown li > ul {
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 272px;
    z-index: 999;
    width: 100%;
    background: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #50a1b5;
    width: 232px;
    padding: 0;
}

#sidebar ul.dropdown li:hover > ul {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

наследует эти свойства :first-child.
можно ли как-то их отменить для вложенного списка, или для него придется заново переопределять :first-child ? 
можно, еще, конечно, задать свойства первого пункта не через :first-child, а через класс, но этого бы делать не хотелось.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#sidebar ul.dropdown > li:first-child
```

Comment: да, действительно, большое спасибо, всё время забываю про этот селектор.